# Dividing LONG by INT and assigning to SHORT - Possible in one case?

Tags: c, winapi, windows-console

I'm manually calculating the number of cells in a Windows console. (Yes, I know this information is available from a filled CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO struct.)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    HANDLE hConsoleOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    RECT workarea;
    COORD c;

    SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_GETWORKAREA, 0, &workarea, 0);
    printf("Rectangle: %ld x %ld\n", workarea.right, workarea.bottom);
    c.X = workarea.right / 8;
    c.Y = workarea.bottom / 12;
    printf("Cells: %d x %d\n", c.X, c.Y);

    return 0;
}
```

The `RECT workarea` is a structure containing four long integers.  The `COORD c` is a structure with two short integers.

When dividing a long integer by an integer (e.g. 8 or 12, as above), is there a problem assigning the resulting constant to a short integer? Visual Studio 2012 produces a compile-time warning as would be expected.

But in testing this particular case, `SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_GETWORKAREA, 0, &workarea, 0)` only gives `RECT workarea` the resolution of my desktop minus the taskbar height (e.g. 1680 x 1010 pixels).

These numbers are, of course, well within the short integer range.  So, I suppose the question is: is there a potential for data loss in this particular case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you divide a `long` with an `int` the result will have data type `long` (the larger of the two). **If** the result fits in a `short` then there will be no data loss when assigning the result to a `short`.

Comment: Good answer, thank you. So if you had `long int i = 100` and wanted to fit it in `short int j`, it would fit.  Is this because `i` is actually `100` and not `0000000100` (a number with 10 places)?

Comment: The integer types in C are always just numbers, so yes, `i` is actually `100`.

Comment: As long as the result of the division is guaranteed to be less than or equal to 32,767 you won't have a problem. If it's greater than that, you'll have numerical overflow. In your case that means your program will work as expected as long as the resolution remains lower than 261408 pixels horizontally and 392112 pixels vertically.